# WinRT ads alternative to Microsoft Pubcenter

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, ads

I wanted to show ads in my application related to the theme of the application. But there is hardly any providers in Microsoft Pubcenter. Is there a alternative that I can use in my application?

If yes than how can I do that?

Comment: Not really sure what's wrong with this question, it is related to app development and ads are integral part of apps now days. Since Windows 8 platform is new I believe this question would have helped lot of people. Ads are tools and components used in the applications developed now days since the question comply with the rules ***•software tools commonly used by programmers***

Comment: You can post a question on [meta] if you want to discuss whether or not this question is indeed on-topic or not.

Comment: Technically this is classified as Not A Real Question, but I'm voting to reopen as the subject is so new and a list can be quite helpful to many others.

Comment: Checkout [What Stack Exchange site would address software suggestion questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132890/what-stack-exchange-site-would-address-software-suggestion-questions).

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative I know of is [AdDuplex](http://www.adduplex.com/) which started up on Windows Phone 7 but is now [available for Windows 8](http://blog.adduplex.com/2012/07/adduplex-for-windows-8-is-here.html) as well. It's a cross-promotion network though, so I'm not sure it's what you're really looking for.

Comment: I looked into AdDuplex, it's interesting idea but not what I need. Thanks for posting though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into adrotator and use multiple ads from pubcenter and adduplex, so you can get 100% fill rate across them.